# Creating a record to a specific Record Type via Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, record-type, aura

In my Apex controller class, I was able to query RecordType using:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Department__c'
```

I am trying to create a record to a specific record type in the Departments custom object and I am not sure how can I specify that record type(with combination of **aura:Iteration** and **aura:if**.

In my Lightning Component(cmp), I am trying this:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.recType}" var="recordType" >
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.recordType.Name == 'Finance'}">
                    Success!
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        False
                    </aura:set>
                </aura:if>
```

I know this will only go to else statement, but how can I get to the specific recordtype? Is there any **contains** formula function which I can use in the if statement?

Comment: Can you expand on this a little - why do you need to do this?

Comment: Hey Caspar, thanks for checking in. I have three different Record types under Departments object. The lightning component which I am working is publicly accessible. So based on the User login status, the form should submit a record to a specific record type, i.e, logged-in user's recordtype should be diff. from a not-logged-in user's recordtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that in your code you have the following attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="recType" type="RecordType "/>
```

And you are filling that attribute in the client controller when the server side action returns the `RecordType` list,

you should use the iteration like this:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.recType}" var="recordType" >
    <aura:if isTrue="{!recordType.Name == 'Finance'}">
```

You do not need the `v.` because this variable is declared in the iteration

Hope it helps

Itai

Comment: Yes, I do have have `<aura:attribute name="recType" type="RecordType[]"/>`. I am using an array of RecordType object, because, I am trying to access a set of record types. 
My apologies for using `v.` again in the `<aura:if>`, even after removal of this, I have no luck. I am not sure exactly how I can be able to get a specific record type from the list.

Comment: print your RecordType[] to the console to see if all data has arrived, also check for case-sensitive issues (is the recordType Finance or finance?)

Comment: Sounds good. I was able to get the solution after a lot of debug. I have used `<aura:if isTrue="{recordType.Name == 'Finance'}">` instead of `<aura:if isTrue="{!recordType.Name == 'Finance'}">`, thus unable to get into the if statement. I only realized once I couldn't go further. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to select a record type in Record creation. If so, check this [link](http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/05/09/custom-record-type-selection-lightning-component/) It may help you.